# Update age SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table called `DOC_ADMISSAO2` where I have the date of birthday (datatype is date) and another date (datatype is date) and I want the age.

I used this query:

```
update DOC_ADMISSAO2 
set IDADE = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATACRIACAO) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATAN)
             from DOC_ADMISSAO2));
```

But it showed me this error:

> Error starting at line : 2 in command - update DOC_ADMISSAO2 set IDADE
>   = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATACRIACAO) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATAN) from DOC_ADMISSAO2) Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01427: subconsulta
>   de linha única devolve mais que uma linha
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Help? I'm kinda new at this.

Comment: Data redundancy. Drop the column IDADE, because it will contain inconsistent data sooner or later. Create a view instead, which does the required calculation - and will always return consistent data!

Comment: #1: This calculation doesn't return an age a human being would expect. #2: As the actual age might change every day this should be calculated and not stored

Comment: I would suggest that you use `months_between() / 12`.  It is more accurate than a difference of years.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: But don't forget to `CAST` it as an INT or apply `FLOOR`, an `age 34.7536882653357754697` looks strange :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a nested query to update your rows:

```
update DOC_ADMISSAO2
set IDADE = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATACRIACAO) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATAN)
```

Of course this computes only the difference between years, so if you have, for example, `DATACRIACAO = 01/01/2016` and `DATAN= 31/12/2015` you will have an age of 1 year.
Besides, as said in the comments, it makes not so much sense to store an age in a table, given that it can change everyday.

So, this could solve your query question, but it would be better to think of a different table design and evaluate the age in some different way.

Comment: It worked. thank you. i used it with "months_between()/12". I need the exact age a person had at a given date, so it doesn't need to change. I only need one more thing. For exaxmple, one of the results is 77.5154. how can i round it to 77?

Comment: @AnaRibeiro: e.g. `TRUNC`, `FLOOR`, `CAST(... AS INT)`